# Creation of user profile page with Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm building a web app with Meteor and the Iron Router and one of my goals is to build a profile view for the user that's logged in (where he can edit his info) and profile view for all the users (which can be viewed by any person).

The profile view of the user logged in works well, but I'm having problems in creating the user profile view for the other users. When I try to access directly in the browser to some user profile with the url (`eg: localhost:3000/users/"id"`) it renders the data of the user logged in and the url in the browser changes to localhost:`3000/users/[object%20Object]`.

Also the  tag with the reference to the is always empty when the page with that info is rendered.

Here is the code related with this problem:

server - `publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('singleUser', function(userId) {
   return Meteor.users.find(userId);
});
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() { 
    this.route('profile', {
        path:'/profile',
        data: function() {return Meteor.user();}
    });

    this.route('user_profile', {
        path: '/users/:_id',
        waitOn: function() {
                return Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.params._id);
        },
        data: function() { 
                var findById = Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id);
                if (typeof findById !== "undefined") {
             Router.go(getProfileUrlById(findById),  {replaceState: true});
                }
        }
    }); 
});
```

User Profile template

```
<template name="user_profile">
    <h4>Username</h4>
    <p>{{username}}</p>
    <h4>Email:</h4>
    <p>{{email}}</p>    
</template>
```

User Profile Helpers

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
     username: function() {return Meteor.user().username},
     email: function() {return Meteor.user().emails[0].address} 
});
```

Item template

```
<template name="item">
    </span> <a href="{{profileUrl}}">{{author}}</a>
</template>
```

Item Helpers

```
Template.item.helpers({
    profileUrl: function() {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId, {reactive:false});
        if(user)
            return getProfileUrlById(user);
    }
 });

getProfileUrlById = function(id) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'users/' + id;
}
```

User Profile logged in template

```
<template name="profile">
    <h4>Username</h4>
    <p>{{username}}</p>
    <h4>Email:</h4>
    <p>{{email}}</p>
</template>
```

User Profile logged in helpers

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    username: function() {return Meteor.user().username},
    email: function() {return Meteor.user().emails[0].address}
 });
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The type of `findById` that you're getting from `Meteor.users.findOne` is an Object, and so when it is cast to a string in `getProfileUrlById`, it ends up being `[object Object]`.  You probably want to pass the `userId` value from the object to that function, not the object itself.

Comment: thanks for the answer. You're suggesting something like this? if (typeof findById !== "undefined") {
     Router.go(getProfileUrlById(findById.userId),  {replaceState: true});
    }

Comment: Can you help me clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem seems to be that you're not publishing private data to the user collection for other users (assuming you have the `autopublish` package uninstalled). Only fields under `profile` are published by default by Meteor. Your `username` field for example is not in `profile` so it will not get published for all users except the one currently logged in.

Secondly, you're overcomplicating route generation. Try generating your route like this:

```html
{{#each users }}
<a href="{{ pathFor 'userAccount' }}">My account</a>
{{/each }}
```

This will automatically use the `_id` field as a key, assuming your router.js file looks like this:

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('userAccount', {
    path: '/users/:_id'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data function for the `user_profile` route is not returning any data, i.e. the return is missing. It should be:

```
data: function() { 
        return Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id);
      }
```

I am not sure what you want to achieve with this (I suggest to remove it)...

```
if (typeof findById !== "undefined") {
     Router.go(getProfileUrlById(findById),  {replaceState: true});
}
```

When the route is used the URL should already be the user's profile id (/users/{id}). Besides that you are calling `getProfileUrlById` with a user object whereas the function expects a user id as string.